# How to run BLE(Bluetooth low energy device) delegate methods(Not beacon) in background in iphone ? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE devices.So that user can get notification for any shop or maul product via bluetooth in iphone by our application.I am not using beacon its BLE device.I have done  BLE(Bluetooth low energy device) delegate  methods run in foreground.But when I On BLE devices ,& app is run in background then delegate methods not getting call.Actually first we want to scan and then connect the BLE device.In background delegate did not work...

I had work on many libraries for BLE background work just like given below:-

```
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=diddiscoverperipheral+advertisementdata

https://github.com/OpenBLE/OpenBLE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I can see that you you have been a user for a couple of years but this is your first post, can I ask that you have a read of [ask] and edit your question to both format the post and make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RichardSlater : whats wrong there in his question. and its not mandatory that the user of stack overflow should must ask the question he can ask whenever he want. and as a best user of stack overflow you should guide the new users instead of depressing them.

Comment: Yes right my friend iShwar,Richard you can not clear with above question ,because you don't know about it.If any iOS developer can read, he/she  will clearly understand what I want from above question.

Comment: @DIPAKDHONDGE you can join the chat room now. please come over there

Comment: I down vote this question becoz you not search regarding your functionality. Well apple mention here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1 how to deal with background execution.

Comment: Hey richard.I am already using above link as reference.Also I reconstruct my .plist as apple document.But nothing happen my delegate can not work.I used lots links and document & libraries.Then I finally post this on stack overflow.Here is my code http://paste.ubuntu.com/15842336/....